# Hiding Live Agent widget in Service Console

Tags: liveagent, service-cloud-console, consoleintegrationtoolkit

I have created a custom console component to use for Live Agent, using the Salesforce Console Integration Toolkit Developer Guide.  I have added it to my console.  It is working fine.  Now that I am using this widget, I want to hide the native Live Agent widget.  Is there any way to do this?  If I uncheck "Include Live Agent in this App" from the App config for the console app, then the native Live Agent widget goes away, but my custom widget no longer works.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Comment: SFDC says there's no solution for this